# How to calculate diode forward voltage (Vd) for a MOSFET within a SEPIC?

Tags: voltage, mosfet, diodes, sepic

I am in the process of selecting a MOSFET for a SEPIC. I require Vd in order to calculate the peak currents across the inductors, which are ultimately needed to calculate the MOSFET peak current, with Vd also being required for the RMS current (associated equations will be provided below). Is there a general equation for calculating Vd for a MOSFET and how do I do so?

**Additional Circuit Info:**

➢ Vin = 15V - 35V

➢ Vout = 25V

➢ Output voltage ripple 1% peak to peak

➢ Switching frequency 100 kHz

➢ Load 10W - 50W

- Converter operates in continuous mode.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need to explain why the internal diode inside a MOSFET will have influence on the charging current for the 1st inductor after the input supply. Also in order to prevent confusion, add a schematic with component references.

Comment: @Andyaka schematic added. Not sure I understand your first point.

Comment: OK, please explain what Vd is in your schematic.

Comment: "Diode voltage for a MOSFET" means, either forward conduction of the body diode, or a "diode strapped" MOSFET with G and D tied so that it becomes a *di-ode* (literally, a two-terminal semiconductor) with a particular Vd(I) characteristic.  The latter is almost only used in ICs, and has no switching value here, so can be ignored. That leaves the body diode.  But your schematic shows only one MOSFET, which never sees reverse drain (forward body) current in normal operation of the surrounding circuit. That leaves D1; are we to assume it is, in fact, a non-switched MOSFET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An assumed value suffices.  The particular solutions to these equations aren't important, as the real circuit will vary due to component values, supply and load conditions, and a controller is used to adjust PWM or peak current as needed.  Only a ballpark solution is needed, and for that, we can assume a typical voltage for D1, such as 0.5V (schottky) to 1.1V (PN diode), or sometimes more (high voltage, fast-recovery PN diodes can drop up to a couple volts).

An assumed value is particularly useful, as otherwise we need to solve a transcendental equation (that is, one where the variable is an exponential function of itself), which can only be approximated numerically.  But an exact solution is neither meaningful nor useful here.  To reach such accuracy overall, we would also need to account for resistance and other parasitic elements of all components, and more exactly model the switching edge.  Parameters we don't even have yet, and would prefer to ignore -- instead assuming they are zero, and later choosing components that meet this assumption.

Note that the two equations always have Vout + Vd together: the effect is simply as though the output were elevated.  D1 is in series with R1 and C2, after all.

To illustrate, consider the case for Vd = 0, 0.5, 1.1 and 2:

$$ I_\text{L1(pk)} = I_\text{OUT} \frac{V_\text{OUT} + V_\text{D}}{V_\text{IN(min)}} \left( 1 + \frac{40\%}{2} \right) $$

If we take the middle case (15V Vin(min), 25V out, 25W = 1A out), we get I_L(pk) of 2.0, 2.04, 2.088 and 2.16A, a range widely exceeded by Vin and Iout ranges; it suffices to take the min/max results to select components.

---

For posterity, this list is easily generated in most PC browsers, by pressing F12 (dev tools), select console tab, and entering this code. Standard disclaimers of running untrusted code apply.

```
IL1 = function(Iout, Vout, Vd, Vinmin) { return Iout * (Vout + Vd) * (1 + 40/100 / 2) / Vinmin; }
VdList = [0, 0.5, 1.1, 2]; ILList = []; VdList.forEach(x => ILList.push(IL1(1, 25, x, 15))); console.log(ILList)
```